# Make ASP.NET MVC Route Id parameter required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-routing

I have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "PlaceDetails",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Place", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This routes this fine:
mysite.com/place/details/123

Making Id 123 available to the details action of the place controller - which can then lookup place '123'.

However - this URL is also passed to the controller:
mysite.com/place/details/

I want this to return `HttpNotFound` - but it sends a null Id to the controller - and requires me to handle that.

It seems neater if the route itself achieves this rather than needing unseemly null checks in the controller itself.

I have found nothing in Google about this specific issue.

How can I do this?

Comment: For reference I now only use attribute routing - way more control, way easier to get your head round.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make the `id` value required, you must not set it as `UrlParameter.Optional` or provide any other default value. With no value in the URL segment, and no default, the route won't match the request.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PlaceDetails",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Place", action = "Details" }
);
```

But you probably also need to constrain the route in another way to prevent it from matching in cases where it shouldn't.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PlaceDetails",
    "Place/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Place", action = "Details" }
);
```

See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/181087) for details and additional options.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the optional for the `id` placeholder in the defaults

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "PlaceDetails",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Place", action = "Details"}
    );
```

Now `mysite.com/place/details/` will not match the route. Provided you don't have another default route mapped.

If the above causes conflicts with your routing you can modify it like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "PlaceDetails",
        "Place/Details/{id}",
        new { controller = "Place", action = "Details"}
    );
```

which couples this mapping directly to `PlaceController.Details` action